# Confusion about CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT handling in DLLs and WM_QUERYENDSESSION

Tags: c, winapi, console, shutdown

My UI is in a DLL. Right now, both the DLL and the EXE that uses it are compiled as console programs so I can use stdout and stderr for debugging and error reporting during development. One of the things is that I have an `uninit()` function that makes sure the DLL isn't leaking memory.

As a result, I have a control handler set up **by the DLL** such that `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT` and `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT` simulate the user clicking the Quit option from the File menu: it does `PostQuitMessage(0)`, with the cleanup code happening after the message pump returns.

I know that normally `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT` cannot be ignored, and that the program **will** terminate after the handler routine returns, regardless of what it returns. But according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> Note that a third-party library or DLL can install a console control handler for your application. If it does, this handler overrides the default handler, and can cause the application to exit when the user logs off.

If I am reading this correctly, this says that a control handler that is installed by a DLL overrides the handler that causes my program to quit when the handler function returns. Am I wrong about that? My DLL's handler function simply returns `TRUE`, which I assume will further stop any other defaults from running given the blurb above.

Why? I'm noticing weird behavior:

On Windows Vista, the program closes regardless of what I do. In this case, I'm wondering if the blurb is wrong and that the handler that terminates the process is still running. This happens regardless of whether I have called `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()`.

On Windows 7, however, it seems that my program's main window gets a `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`, and Windows responds to it accordingly. That means that if I say "no, don't quit yet (don't call `PostQuitMessage(0)`)" in my Quit function, Windows pops up the "an application is preventing shutdown" screen saying my main window is preventing shutdown. In that case, the blurb above appears to be correct, as the program is not quitting on return from the console handler (if it's even being called!).

If I instead say "yes, call `PostQuitMessage(0)`, the program quits normally. However, I lose the debugging output on stdout and stderr, so I can't tell if it really is quitting normally or not. Invoking my program as

```
new.exe > out.txt 2> err.txt
```

on `cmd.exe` produces two empty files; I don't know why the output isn't saving on system shutdown (and Googling doesn't turn up any information).

So can someone help clear up my confusion so I can implement this (including `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()`) properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return TRUE from the handler you registered, Windows immediately terminates the process.  When you return FALSE, the previous handler gets called.  Ultimately that will be the default handler, it immediately terminates the process.

So what you have to do is not return and block until you are happy.  That requires synching with the thread that's pumping the message loop.  You'd use an event, the pumping thread can call SetEvent() after its message loop and your handler can call WaitForSingleEvent() to block after it called PostQuitMessage().

It is however a threading race, your UI thread was probably started by main() and the CRT is going to terminate the program when main() returns.  Which one will get there first is a unpredictable.

---

Having the feeling you are doing something wrong?  Well, you are.  A console window just isn't a very good way to display debug output.  Not sure why you are doing this but I know your tool-chain is unusual, I can never get any of your code snippets to compile and run.  The proper way is OutputDebugString().  That function talks to your debugger and gets it to display text.  Even if your debugger isn't capable of displaying such text, you can still fallback to SysInternals' DebugView utility.

Your are probably using printf() and won't enjoy fixing all your debug statements, simply write your own version of that links ahead of the CRT, use vprintf() and OutputDebugStringA().

Comment: Right, seeing if I was doing something wrong was part of what led to this question. I'm very curious about you not being able to compile my examples. My toolchain right now is MinGW-w64, though I try not to use anything specific to that and want to make this and a few other projects compilable with Microsoft's compilers (and others) as well. Definitely worth investigating... I'll consider switching to OutputDebugString(). My main reason for using the console was convenience, and I was going to turn off the console later in development; I can use dbgview until then (I have it already). Thanks.

Comment: All right, I've tried dbgview and windbg and gdb; none of them last long enough to tell me any of the debugging messages after my `PostQuitMessage(0)` (which verifies memory has been freed). Is this expected indeterminedness of system shutdown? Should I even bother testing this edge case (proper cleanup of my library on system shutdown)? I assume I wanted to because of my responsibility as a library author to clean up after myself...

Comment: Hmm, no, there is no decent way to see what happened when the OS shuts down.  It just doesn't matter, all them bits are gonzo anyway.  All that matters is that you respond to the shutdown, not doing so is very easy to see.  You only care about proper cleanup on program termination so you'll have a decent shot at diagnosing leaks.  Normal termination, not the kind forced by an OS shutdown.

Comment: All right; in that case I'll stop worrying. Thanks. (I'll still need to investigate why my code samples don't work outside my current environment...)